# Is there a big difference in perfomance between querying mongodb or using js for making reports?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'd like to know what approach is more performant for creating a report based on some data from DB. If we need to collect data from 3 different collections in DB would it be less performant if I first get all needed data and then parse them into the report using javascript on backend? I know most of operations I can make inside of mongodb query but it would make that query too complicated. So how big is the difference between those two approaches?

Comment: This sort of thing can only be answered by *trying it* and seeing which is faster.  We don't know the performance characteristics of your db instance or how complicated your reports are.  You need to benchmark it.

Comment: Impossible for us to know. Implement both and measure them.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'm just wondering if there is a big difference by default.

Comment: There is no "default".